# JDO: referencing a collection of entities "owned" by another class

Tags: google-app-engine, orm, jdo

I have a [RecipeJDO](http://pastebin.com/f33e4041) that contains a List<[IngredientJDO](http://pastebin.com/f168e661a)>.  `RecipeJDO` "owns" the ingredients.  This has been working well for me for several weeks.  Now I'd like to introduce a new class "[GroceryListJDO](http://pastebin.com/f2d2ac7b3)", that references the ingredients owned by various recipes.

When I try to persist a new `GroceryListJDO` I get the following:

```
javax.jdo.JDOException: Duplicate property name: ingredients_id_OWN
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Duplicate property name: ingredients_id_OWN
javax.jdo.JDOException: Duplicate property name: ingredients_id_OWN
```

Seems like there is an issue of "ownership" of the ingredients between `RecipeJDO` and `GroceryListJDO`.

I could probably change `GroceryListJDO` to merely contain a `List<String>` that acts as a kind of foreign key to `IngredientsJDO`, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using ORM- I'd have to manually fetch and attach the ingredients in my DAO.

**What is the best way to manage JDO collections that need to "attach" to multiple container JDO classes?**

This is with JDO on Google App Engine, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is known as an "unowned" relationship, and is [not directly supported](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Unowned_Relationships) in GAE.  The workaround is what I feared: only one JDO class can own the collection; any other JDOs that reference these objects must persist only `Keys,` and manage the fetching/saving of the referenced objects manually.